# Displayed fieldset values to save into object

Tags: visualforce

I have few fieldsets which are collection of checkbox, i want to retrieve their values and save as child records to cases.  This is the code, please help me in writing the save action.

**Controller**

```
public class ShowDocumentChecklistController {
    private string caseID = '';
    public Account acc { get; set; }
    public Case caseItem { get; set; }
    public DocumentList__c dl { get; set; }


    public ShowDocumentChecklistController() {
        list<case>caseList = new list<case>();
        this.dl = getdl();

        caseID = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('caseId');
        if (caseList.isEmpty() == false) {
            caseItem = caseList[0];
        } else {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'The case ID is invalid.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);

        }
    }

    public List <Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.DocumentList__c.FieldSets.Red_Items.getFields();
    }

    private DocumentList__c getdl() {
        String query = 'SELECT ';

        for (Schema.FieldSetMember f: this.getFields()) {
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }

        query += 'Id, Name FROM DocumentList__c where Case__c = :caseID order by LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1';

        return Database.query(query);
    }

    public pageReference saveRecord() {
        DocumentList__c dl = new DocumentList__c(); 

      ? ? ? ?
        insert dl;
        return returnToOrigination();
    }

    public pageReference cancelAction() {
        return returnToOrigination();
    }

    private pageReference returnToOrigination() {
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + caseID);
        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
    }
}
```

**VF page**

```
 <apex:page controller="ShowDocumentChecklistController">
     <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Document Checklist"/>
        <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelAction}"/>
           <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageblocksection>
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.DocumentList__c.FieldSets.Green_Items}" var="g">  
                                              <apex:inputfield value="{!documentlist[g]}">  
                                              </apex:inputfield> 
                                          </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
public class ShowDocumentChecklistController{


    public DocumentList__c docList{ get; set; }

    public ShowDocumentChecklistController() {
    String caseID = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('caseId');

        this.docList= getDocumentList(caseID);
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.DocumentList__c.FieldSets.Red_Items.getFields();
    }

    private DocumentList__c getDocumentList(String caseID) {


        String query = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }
        query += 'Id, Name FROM DocumentList__c where Case__c = :caseID order by LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1';
        return Database.query(query);
    }

    public pageReference saveRecord(){

        update docList;
    }

}
```

```
  <apex:pageBlock title="abc">
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="abcd">
          <apex:inputField value="{!docList.Name}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

      <apex:pageBlockSection title="xyz">
          <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
              <apex:inputField value="{!docList[f.fieldPath]}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```